# Custom file Tree API like github rest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, filesystems, mern

I want to fetch a folder/directory from my node server with all files and subdirectory like Github file tree api and show it to react frontend just like VS code file tree where user can add delete and edit file on the web. Basically I want to build a web IDE where user can do do coding for this purpose I need to sync file system from frontend to backend. Is there any opensource library where i can develop REST/websocket to sync files and folders with backend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[SMB protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) have been used for a long time to implement network filesystems, and it has a free implementation [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)).